# How to use mse function - babynames example

Tags: r

So I am using the 'babynames' package in rstudio and am trying to get the 35 most common unisex names. I am trying to rank the names based on the mean squared error from the 50-50 line (however, I am not sure how to do this). Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Also below my code I will put the 'reference code' we were given that includes what the top 35 unisex names are)

Reference Code:

```
actual_names <- c("Jessie", "Marion", "Jackie", "Alva", "Ollie",
                  "Jody", "Cleo", "Kerry", "Frankie", "Guadalupe", 
                  "Carey", "Tommie", "Angel", "Hollis", "Sammie",
                  "Jamie", "Kris", "Robbie", "Tracy", "Merrill", 
                  "Noel", "Rene", "Johnnie", "Ariel", "Jan", 
                  "Devon", "Cruz", "Michel", "Gale", "Robin", 
                  "Dorian", "Casey", "Dana", "Kim", "Shannon")
```

Comment: I would suggest getting the male and female totals per name together, something like `babynames %>% filter(year >= 1930, year <= 2012) %>% count(name, sex, wt = n) %>% spread(sex, n)`. Then you could `mutate` from the two resulting columns to get the percentage split, and the associated RMS error from 50/50.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few ways to answer the question as posed, since there's a tradeoff between "most popular" and "most unisex."

Here's a way to prep the data to collect some stats for each name.

```
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)
babynames_share <-
  babynames %>%
  filter(year >= 1930, year <= 2012) %>%
  count(name, sex, wt = n) %>% 
  spread(sex, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(Total = F + M,  
         F_share = F / Total,
         MS_50 = ((F_share-0.5)^2 + 
               (0.5-F_share)^2) / 2)
```

It looks like around 100 names have perfect gender parity -- but they're all quite uncommon:

```
babynames_share %>%
  filter(F == M) %>%
  arrange(-Total) 
# A tibble: 100 x 6
   name         F     M Total F_share RMS_50
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Tyjae      157   157   314     0.5      0
 2 Callaway   128   128   256     0.5      0
 3 Avyn       100   100   200     0.5      0
 4 Zarin       92    92   184     0.5      0
 5 Tkai        72    72   144     0.5      0
 6 Rayen       57    57   114     0.5      0
 7 Meco        43    43    86     0.5      0
 8 Pele        40    40    80     0.5      0
 9 Nijay       35    35    70     0.5      0
10 Mako        27    27    54     0.5      0
# … with 90 more rows
```

Or we might pick some arbitrary threshold for what counts as unisex. In the example above, I've calculated the mean squared error for the female and male percent shares. We can plot that to see very gendered names on the top (MS_50 tops out at 0.25 by this measure), and unisex names toward the bottom. But it isn't obvious to me how far down we should go to count a name as unisex. Is Casey, which is 58.9% male, with therefore an 8.9%^2 = 0.79% squared error, unisex? Or do we need to further to Jessie, which is 50.8% male?

```
babynames_share %>%
  ggplot(data = .,
         aes(Total, MS_50, label = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.2, alpha = 0.1, color = "gray30") +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(Total > 10000),
            check_overlap = TRUE, size = 3) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(10^(1:7)), 
                labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

At the "Casey" level of gender parity, here are the top 35:

```
unisex_names <- babynames_share %>% 
  filter(MS_50 <= 0.00796) %>%
  arrange(-Total) %>%
  top_n(35, wt = Total)
```

It's also interesting to see the whole spectrum of names, with most male on the bottom, female on the top, and unisex in the middle:

```
babynames_share %>%
  ggplot(data = .,
         aes(Total, F_share, label = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.2, alpha = 0.1, color = "gray30") +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(Total > 10000),
            check_overlap = TRUE, size = 2) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(10^(1:7)), 
                labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! From what I understand, there is no designated place to "end" to count a name as unisex. However, I looked at all the names in the list individually, and all the names have at least a total of 9,000 babies over the 1930-2012 time span with that name.

Comment: I edited above to make clearer that you could use the "as unisex as Casey" definition to get one list of the most popular unisex names. That's just one definition/threshold though -- if you have a specific one in mind, please include it in the question.